# why my DAQ signal is a noisy signal?

Tags: adc, data, distortion, aliasing

### background:

My goal is to use an Arduino with two proximity probe (sensors) to achieve some output.

It is worth mentioning that the output of the proximity probe has two components:

- DC output that determines the position or the GAP
- AC component on the top of that DC voltage to determine the vibration

The proximity probe sensor has a negative voltage output from -5 to -12 volt DC and then the AC is on the top of the DC,

I have two parts in my circuit to achieve two outputs suitable for Arduino as they should be from 0-5 volt

1. the first one is to get the AC of the signal, as appears on the
   upper part of the whole circuit, the filter is a second order
   high-pass filter to separate the AC from the DC, which will give an
   AC output oscillating around zero volt. This output needs to be
   shifted up by 2.5 volts so that my signal will be centered around
   2.5 volt not zero. the two resistors as a voltage divider will take care of that.
2. the second part is to get the raw signal , what I am doing basically
   is that, I have a 15 volt adapter to shift the negative sensor
   signal and then two resistors as a voltage divider, so that will
   make the signal suitable for arduino example: if my signal is -7
   volt DC and 1 volt AC , the shifting circuit will shift the signal
   by 15 to be + 8 volt and then this 8 volt will go through a voltage
   divider as appears on the lower part of the signal

[image]

---

### The experiment and testing:

I tested the system on a more realistic environment ( which is pump driven by a motor in a plant )

to compare my DAQ with an industrial and already proven DAQ, I captured the same signal for both of them.

lets just look at the AC part

and here we can see the two signals

this is the signal captured by my DAQ
[image]

and here is the signal captured from the industrial DAQ

[image]

***we can see that my signal is totally distorted!***

---

I suspected **3 factors** for this distortion

1. the Resolution of my ADC
2. aliasing
3. time synchronization

and this is how I approached each of these:

**1. the resolution:**

the resolution of my ADC is 9.5 bits in a reference voltage 5 volt

which will give us  5/(2^(9.5)) = 6.9 mv step which is good enough I guess

the resolution of that ADC is 12 bits, but I am not sure about the reference voltage

I ran another experiment in the office to see if my ADC can capture this small voltage which is in the range of 300 mv

and the results were fine

[image]

as we can see my DAQ can capture these small voltages

**2. aliasing**

my DAQ sampling frequency is 5000 Hz. Figure below shows the FFT of the signal from the test that was carried on in the realistic environment. As we can see, there is no frequency components above 1500 Hz.

[image]

The bandwidth of the signal is around 2500 Hz and my DAQ sampling frequency is 5000 Hz. Aliasing only happens if there is frequency above 2500 Hz. From the above figure, there are no frequency components above 2500 Hz and there is no way aliasing can occur.

**3. Time synchronization**

During the test, the data taken from the industrial DAQ and my DAQ were not synchronized.So the data is different to one another. It is hard to synchronize the two DAQs and signal may not be steady

the question is ! what other reasons may cause this distortion? and how to overcome it?

and comments and observations are higly appreciated

Comment: Since you have it all already built in hardware, it should be easy to figure out what the signals are at certain points with an oscilloscope. From that on you can see where the signal starts being distorted, or if it maybe already looks that way when it comes into your hardware.

Comment: @PlasmaHH thanks for the reply, 
the problem is, the site is too far! and before I go there to test it again with an oscilloscope, I need to make sure that I took care of all the problematic factors

Comment: do you have your system at hand? inject a somewhat realistic clean signal into it

Comment: @PlasmaHH yeah its at hand now, I already used a function generator, and the results are fine, the signal is in the question.what do you mean by " somewhat realistic clean" signal?

Comment: How do you distinguish between mains hum (electrical interference) and motor/pump vibration?

Comment: @SabirMoglad: injecting a pure sine wave might hide amplification/interaction of signal noise. injecting random noise will not show how your circuit adds noise, so what you need to inject needs to be in between. a bit noise to look realistic, but not too much to hide your circuits behaviour. for a future reference you might want to do a high res capture of your real signal, filter that a bit, and replay it with a good awg.

Comment: ah, one point that just popped into my mind is: have you compared yours and the "industry proven" devices input impedance?

Comment: @BrianDrummond if I understand you correctly, in order to distinguish, we need to know exactly how the mains hum or the motor vibration looks like and then we can filter out one of them,  I have no clue how they look I just get all of the signals into my system.

I am using just a high pass filter to remove the DC component

Comment: @PlasmaHH I partially got your point,

high res capture = high resolution capture ? 
and what is awg ? 

no actually I haven't compared the input impedance, what does that indicate

Comment: @SabirMoglad: yes, high res, and awg is an arbitrary waveform generator